# Conclude the "MVT for scalar fields"- proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, scalar-fields

[image]
So, e.g $f=a^2+b^2$ (red function in the picture). For two points $x,y$ $\in$ $(-3,3)\times(-3,3)$ we define $g$ as $g: f(ty+(1-t)x)$, and that will be the gray curve. MVT says, there is a $t \in(0,1)$ such that $g(1)-g(0)=g'(t)$, so $f(y)-f(x) = g'(t)$. I want to show the MVT for scalar fields, means there is a $\xi$ with $f(y)-f(x) = \langle \mathrm{grad}f(\xi), y-x\rangle.$ How to transform $g'(t)$ $\textbf{formally}$ correct into the scalar product I need, like $g'(t) = \ldots = \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$?

Comment: I do not understand your point. The picture shows a function $f$ defined on $(-3,3)\times(-3,3)=\Omega$, which is differentiable. We have two points $A$ and $B$ that are $\in \Omega$, and $[A,B]$ that is also in $\Omega$. That means we have everything to use the mean value theorem. What details you nead more? What is not clear? You can either delete this post if you don't like it, or explain what do you not understand, but I do not get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2),\mathbf y=(y_1,y_2)$ then $t\mathbf y+(1-t)\mathbf x=\left(x_1+(y_1-x_1)t,x_2+(y_2-x_2)t\right)$.

So $$g(t)=(x_1+(y_1-x_1)t)^2 + (x_2+(y_2-x_2)t)^2$$

So $$\begin{align}g'(t)&=2(x_1+(y_1-x_1)t)(y_1-x_1)+2(x_2+(y_2-x_2)t)(y_2-x_2)\\
&=2(x_1(y_1-x_1)+x_2(y_2-x_2))+2t\left((y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2\right)\\
&=2\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y-\mathbf x\rangle +2t\langle \mathbf y-\mathbf x,\mathbf y-\mathbf x\rangle\\
&=2\langle t\mathbf y+(1-t)\mathbf x,\mathbf y-\mathbf x\rangle
\end{align} $$

Comment: thank you for the answer. The third $y_1$ in the first line of the derivative should be $x_2$. 1) I do not understand what you do going from the first line of $g'(t)$ to the second. 2) Why $2ty + 2(1-t)x$ is the $\mathrm{grad}f(t)$? 3) Is the question so awful that I got $-2$ points for that?

Comment: yes, you've forgotten a pair of $()$ in the second line. It should be $=2(x_1(y_1-x_1)+x_2(y_2-x_2)) \ldots$

Comment: the rest questions are clear now